# How can I reliably assign object to a newly created window (window.open)

Tags: javascript, object, race-condition, window.open

I have an object in my parent window containing nested objects from a previous ajax call, but for simplicity, let say it looks like this:

```
var myStuff = { id:1, computer:"ZX Spectrum" };
```

I need to open a popup window and pass a reference to the object to it.  Therefore I have:

```
this.oPopup = window.open("/my/page.htm", "MyPopupTarget", opts, false);
this.oPopup.myStuff = myStuff;
```

Usually this works fine but I do occasionally get exceptions occurring on the 2nd line and sometimes I get an exception occurring in the popup window when it finds "myStuff" variable doesn't exist.

I suspect this is a timing issue but I would like to know how to pass the myStuff object down reliably.  Should I wrap it in an setTimeout()?  Is there an event I can listen on?

Thanks.

Comment: I would recommend having the popup reach into the parent window instead. Then you don't have to worry about timing: Make it available before ever opening the popup and the popup can grab it whenever it loads.

Comment: Thanks Dark Falcon.  I did originally work on this premise.  I read somewhere that top down would be more reliable but I'll have to go back to the original source of that suggestion and iron out the reasoning for it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you provide exactly what type of exception is being thrown.

Might be a threading issue with the new window accessing the data before it's populated. You could try creating the window object and assigning the "myStuff" variable, then separately calling the Open method, that way all the data is assigned before it opens.

Comment: I've caught the error and alerted out the properties of the exception.  There are only three properties however (fileName, lineNumber and columnNumber) all useful and correct values but no type property (was expecting a null reference or undefined or similar).  

We are using FireFox (latest).

Catch code is:
    catch(e)
    {
        var s = "";
        for(n in e)
           s += "."+n+"="+e[n]+"\n";
        alert(s);
        }